# CoreData and pre-filled DB

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I need to prepare my IOS application with a Pre-filled DB. I'm wondering whether my technique is good of if it leaks in something:

1. At the first App launch: Call a function that fill data in DB, only if field "DB_filled" in property list is equal to "NO".
2. When function completes and data is stored in DB: setup plist with "DB_filled" => YES.
3. At the next App launch: DB_filled is equal to YES, thus, no other attempts to pre fill Db are done.

I'm not sure this's the correct technique. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most common scenario for first-launch app setup except for variances in key name (firstLaunch, FirstLaunch or SetupDone, or, in your case, DB_filled). Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525781/whats-the-most-common-scenario-for-cocoa-app-setup-during-first-launch) too.